# Retain EF Code First model in memory

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have few different wpf windows, for example sales.xaml, buy.xaml.

Both of the windows is using the same EF code first model, sales.cs.

I have added some value to the sales model in sales.xaml, how can I retrieve the same model in buy.xaml from sales.xaml, when the sales.xaml is close.

If I didn't make the model attributes to static, the data will be lost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to declare the instance of your model as a StaticResource and then access that on each page, setting the instance to the DataContext as necessary.

```
<Application.Resources>
 <Example:ViewModel x:Key="VM"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

...

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource VM}"/>
 </UserControl.DataContext>
```

If you do this on each page, then any changes should persist to the instance that's stored globally in the Application's ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Do not, under any circumstances, make your data context static.  Do not use a singleton.  Do not make it global.

Always instantiate a new data context when you need to do a data operation.  When the operation is completely, you call SaveChanges so that the next time you need it, the data will be returned.

The reason is that Data contexts are designed to be short lived.  If you make the context static, it will never be destroyed for the lifetime of the app.  It will continue to grow the object caches until it will eventually run out of memory.

Data contexts have no abort, or rollback functionality.  They are designed to be thrown away at the end of a logical operation.  Let's say you add an entity to your data context, and then SaveChanges..  If there is an error, there is no way to remove the data you just added.  The only supported way is to destroy the context.